# C# Максимальная сумма элементов T в List<T>

Tags: c#, list

Всем привет, есть `List<T>`

```
    class T
{
    public double T1 { get; set; }
    public double T2 { get; set; }
    public double T3 { get; set; }
    public double T4 { get; set; }
}
```

Каким образом можно определить лист с максимальной суммой элементов?
Например

```
T1 T2 T3 T4

{1, 2, 3, 4}

{5, 6, 7, 8}

{5, 4, 1, 8}
```

T4 - максимальный, т.к. сумма его элементов равна 20

Comment: Не понятно, чего вы хотите. Вы говорите "есть `List<T>`" и указываете класс `T` состоящий из 4 свойств. Это ок. Но далее вы спрашиваете, как определить `list` с максимальной суммой элементов. Может быть, вы имеете ввиду не list, а объект `T` в списке `list`, у которого сумма `T1+T2+T3+T4` максимальная? или имеете ввиду определить имя свойства с максимальной суммой (т.е. `list[0].T4 + list[1].T4 + list[2].T4`)?

Comment: `int max = list.Max(elem => elem.T1 + elem.T2 + elem.T3 + elem.T4); T maxElem = list.First(elem => elem.T1 + elem.T2 + elem.T3 + elem.T4 == max);`

Comment: Скоро можно будет и проще: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/abd01f544049fe32aefda440efd98a7ff3e52583/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Max.cs#L516

Answer (score 0):

В классе Т сделай свойство Sum, которое будет возвращать сумму элементов. А потом используй вот такой способ определения максимума:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32__